# Android NotSerializableException raises for an object

Tags: java, android, serialization

In my **android** application I use a **file to store license data**. And I uses **Serialize objects**. I create a **Device** object and read the file details in to the object. **Device class implements Serializable**.

```
public class MyDevice implements Serializable {}
```

But at the start of application it **deserialize** and store in a MyDevice  object. My **deserializeObject** method is as below.

```
public MyDevice deserializeObject() {

    File SerialFile = new File(GeoTrackerPaths.FILE_PATH);
    MyDevice AndDeviceIn = new MyDevice();

    if (SerialFile.exists()) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(GeoTrackerPaths.FILE_PATH);
            ObjectInputStream objInput = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            AndDeviceIn = (MyDevice) objInput.readObject();
            objInput.close();
            fileIn.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.i("TAG", "Exception during deserialization:" + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    return AndDeviceIn;
}
```

My serialization code

```
public void serializeObject(Context context, String phoneModel,
        String androidVersion, String executiveCode, String Key,
        String modelID, String tempKey, int noLogin, String expireDate, String Status) {

    try {
        MyDevice AndDeviceOut = new MyDevice(context, phoneModel,
                androidVersion, new Date(), executiveCode, Key, modelID,
                tempKey, noLogin, expireDate, Status);

        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(
                GeoTrackerPaths.FILE_PATH);
        ObjectOutputStream objOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
        objOutput.writeObject(AndDeviceOut);
        objOutput.flush();
        objOutput.close();
        fileOut.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("TAG", "Exception during serialization:" + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

And I'm calling it as below.

```
DeviceActivator activate=new DeviceActivator();
activate.serializeObject(Activation.this, phoneModel, androidVersion, txtExe, exeKey, modeilID, tempKey, noLogin, expireDate, Activation_Status);
```

when I'm running the app following exceptions are raised.

```
java.io.WriteAbortedException: Read an exception; 
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.geotracker.entity.MyDevice
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Not related to exception but why are you creating new MyDevice object and then assigning the same reference to object you read from file?

Comment: you mean "MyDevice AndDeviceIn = new MyDevice();" isn't it. shouldn't I create a MyDevice instance to store the object..........

Comment: Nothing looks wrong with your example de-serialization code, could be an issue with your code that does the serialization process. Can you post that part as well?

Comment: OK I'll post the serialization part....

Comment: I don't believe the Android `Context` object is serializable.  Try removing it and run the process again to see if that's the issue

Comment: There are some reference in MyDevice that are not serializable. You can make them as transient.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't look like the Android [`Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) object is serializable.  You can solve this by declaring the `Context` object as transient, which you can read about in here in the JDK spec: [Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.3). Basically marking a field as transient means it won't participate in Serialization

So declare your field like this in `MyDevice` :

`private transient Context context;`

and you should be good to go!